# Have I imported something wrong

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
from random import shuffle

mylist = [' ','O',' ']

my_new_list = shuffle_list(mylist)

guess = player_guess

check_guess(my_new_list,guess)

def shuffle_list(list):
    shuffle(list)
    return list

def player_guess():
    
    guess = ''
    while guess not in ['0','1','2']:
        guess = input("pick a number: 0 , 1 , 2")
    return int(guess)

def check_guess(mylist,guess):
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        print(mylist)
```

I receive this error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 5>()
      1 from random import shuffle
      3 mylist = [' ','O',' ']
----> 5 my_new_list = shuffle_list(mylist)
      7 guess = player_guess
      9 check_guess(my_new_list,guess)

NameError: name 'shuffle_list' is not defined
```

Comment: put `my_new_list = shuffle_list`  below the function definition

Comment: You have to define the function first.

Comment: You are trying to use `shuffle_list` before you define it. It's like saying make me a sandwich but theres no bread

Comment: functions need to be declared before being used. It runs top down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python reads scripts from top to bottom, so when it reaches the line where you call `shuffle_list` python doesn't yet know what `shuffle_list` is and so it throws an exception.  All you need to do to fix it is to move the lines with function calls to the bottom.

```
from random import shuffle

mylist = [' ','O',' ']

def shuffle_list(list):
    shuffle(list)
    return list

def player_guess():
    
    guess = ''
    while guess not in ['0','1','2']:
        guess = input("pick a number: 0 , 1 , 2")
    return int(guess)

def check_guess(mylist,guess):
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong guess!")
        print(mylist)

# All of the code below can't run until the functions have been defined 

my_new_list = shuffle_list(mylist)
guess = player_guess   # You probably want to call this e.g. player_guess()
check_guess(my_new_list,guess)
```